# Python gtk: ComboBoxEntry with Enum

Tags: python-2.7, combobox, enums, pygtk

I'm really trying hard to find an example to create Enum and send it as a model to ComboBoxEntry.

Can someone upload an example of the proper way to do so?

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
model = "one", "two", "three"
liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
for item in model:
    liststore.append([item])
cbe = gtk.ComboBoxEntry(liststore)
```

I want *model* to be enum for the ability to write:

```
# for example:
cbe.set_active(one)
# or
if cbe.get_active() == model.one: ...
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
    ##  Length
    nLines      = tableData.data.shape[0]
    ##  Width
    nColons     = len(tableData.columns)
    ##  +1 adds an extra column for numbering (at the left side)
    types       = [str] * (nColonnes + 1)
    ##  build it
    modelT      = gtk.ListStore( * types )
```

and this should work for you :

```
>>> model = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> types = [str] * len(model)
>>> lists = gtk.ListStore( * types )
```

Comment: Sorry, i just want the "model" will be Enum. so when I'll write: **myComboBoxEntry.set_active(one)** it will work

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4 has a new [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) data type (also avalaible is the [enum34 backport](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) and an [advanced enum library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)).  To install `enum34` or `aenum`:

- `pip install enum34`, or
- `pip install aenum`

After that you could make `model` be an `Enum` like so:

```
from enum import Enum    # or from aenum import Enum

class Model(str, Enum):
    one = 'one'
    two = 'two'
    three = 'three'
```

with these results:

```
>>> list(Model)
[<Model.one: 'one'>, <Model.two: 'two'>, <Model.three: 'three'>]

>>> Model.one
<Model.one: 'one'>

>>> Model.one == 'one'
True
```